# can I travel to France when I have a German aufenthaltstitel that is valid for three years

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, german-residents

I'm an Indian citizen. I married a German citizen and now I have a aufenthaltstitel(A plastic card) with the right to work.

Am I allowed to travel into France by Train? Or do I need a visa. I have an Indian passport.

Where would I call or check to confirm or ask about this?

Last month I still had a fiktionsbescheinigung and had trouble with french border police.

Answer (score 6):

The German *Aufenthaltstitel* is a residence permit for the purpose of the Schengen codes (and probably for every other purpose).  As such, it allows you to travel to other Schengen countries.  See, for example, [Travel documents for non-EU nationals](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm):

> If you have a valid residence permit from one of those Schengen countries, it is equivalent to a visa. You may need a national visa to visit non-Schengen countries.

As the last sentence implies, your residence permit does not help you enter the UK or Ireland.  France, however, should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

France will consider you a resident of German visiting. Keep your passport and Aufenthaltstitel with you at all times and then its no problem.